# Remove Shield Icon from programs with UAC

Tags: c++, uac

With C++, when compiling your `.exe` file and you have to specify it to run as an admin, is there any way to remove the shield icon? I've seen programs do it, and I spent some time trying to find out how to do it as well, but I have not found a clear answer.

Comment: Which shield icon are you referring to exactly? Is your `.exe` file code-signed?

Comment: Yes the .exe that one

Comment: Does any of this help?  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-remove-uac-shield-icon-overlay/8490d128-6831-4b5a-a6db-7f289c6af435

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The shield icon indicates the executable will run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the shield overlay icon, it is there for a reason.

Programs that **might** need UAC elevation can mark themselves asInvoker in their manifest and use `ShellExecute` to elevate at run-time.